# How to dynamically inject children components into parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I dynamically inject child components into parent? for example to turn this:

```
<Parent>
  <Child/>
  <Child/>
</Parent>
```

into this:

```
<Parent>
  <Child/>
  <Child/>
  <Child/>
</Parent>
```

Without using the usual solution which is obviously `map`. The thing is, there is a library that it's API work by counting the `props.children` property of the component so, the `map` function not really work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use React's `Children` helper

```
const Component = ({children}) =>{
    return React.Children.map(children, child =>{
        return React.cloneElement(child, {childProps : 'foo'})
    })
}
```